# Get form data specifying the key on Webapis using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am currently using this code to get my form data using web apis and MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

```
   await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the form data.
            foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
                }
            }
```

Is it possible to get the form data not using the foreach loops but specifing the key? Using something like this var name = Form["txtFormValue"];

I already tried  string r = provider.FormData.("form-email"); but it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a specific key by calling the `GetValues()` method directly, passing it the key you want the value for.

EX:

```
string email = provider.FormData.GetValues("form-email").SingleOrDefault();
```

`.SingleOrDefault();` is called because `GetValues()` returns a collection (multiple items) and you only want one.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the SingleOrDefault method